# Why incrementing 0 returns uncaught syntax error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have:
`0++`

and it returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix 
operation
```

Why?

`typeof(0)` returns a "number"

So I would expect 0++ to return 1?

Comment: Because `++` only makes sense on a variable. Makes no sense to increase a number literal.

Comment: Also: "*So I would expect 0++ to return 1?*" why would it return `1` even if you had `x = 0; x++`? Postfix will return the initial value and then increment.

Comment: If you really want to plus plus `0`, then should do 

`[[]][0]++`

Answer (score 4):

`0++` is equivalent to `0 = 0 + 1`.

You can't assign a value to a value (only to a property or variable).

Answer (score 0):

Assign that 0 to a variable and increment that.

```
var someValue = 0;
someValue++;
```